# Cosmos DB stored procedure does not return results when comparing against sproc argument in filter

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing a stored procedure which will be creating a "view" so-to-speak for the `UI`.

Given the following documents currently in the DB:

```
[{
  "id": "e635ac09-3820-48be-a899-d4d2c91bf3c2"
  "organizationId": "18697a1c-f02b-4974-b1ab-f5f6c4932de6",
  "type": "EnvironmentDocument"
},
{
  "id": "c19a8293-e198-4c9a-abda-7605473d3ebb"
  "organizationId": "18697a1c-f02b-4974-b1ab-f5f6c4932de6",
  "type": "EnvironmentDocument"
}]
```

Where `organizationId` is the partition key.

This is my WIP:

```
function getTaskSummary(organizationId) {
    const context = getContext();

    const main = async () => {
        const container = context.getCollection();
        const environments = await fetchEnvironmentIds(container, organizationId);
        return environments;
    };

    main().then(summary => context.getResponse().setBody(summary))
        .catch(error => context.abort(error));
}

function fetchEnvironmentIds(container, organizationId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const predicate = doc =>
            doc.organizationId === organizationId
            && doc.type === 'EnvironmentDocument';  

        const result = container.chain().filter(predicate).map(doc => doc.id)
            .value((error, docs) => {
                if (error) { reject(error); }
                else { resolve(docs); }
            });

        if (!result.isAccepted) {
            reject(new Error('Failed to fetch environment document IDs'));
        }
    });
}
```

Within the stored procedure, I first need to fetch all of the `EnvironmentDocument`'s for a given `organizationId`.

I pass the `organizationId` to the stored procedure and attempt to `filter` the documents by both `type` and `organizationId` within the `fetchEnvironmentIds` function.

The issue I'm having is when I attempt to compare the documents `organizationId` property to the stored procedure's argument I get no results returned (empty array with no error).

I've done some print debugging and I see that the `organizationId` is passed successfully to the stored procedure (I've removed all of the `console.log` statements above).

I tried trimming the passed in `organizationId` within the stored procedure just in case there was some white space I didn't notice but this was not the case.

What **does** work is if I instead hard code the `organizationId` within the `filter` I *do* get results returned as I expected:

```
const predicate = doc =>
  doc.organizationId === '18697a1c-f02b-4974-b1ab-f5f6c4932de6'
  && doc.type === 'EnvironmentDocument';
```

I also of course ran the following query within the Cosmos DB data explorer which also returns the results I expected:

```
SELECT * FROM c 
    WHERE c.type = 'EnvironmentDocument' 
    AND c.organizationId = '18697a1c-f02b-4974-b1ab-f5f6c4932de6'
```

I'm currently testing this stored procedure in the Cosmos DB data explorer (I'm not calling this from an application using an SDK).

Currently I'm passing the values as shown in the image below:

[image]

I'm admittedly a bit perplexed here. I'm unsure why using the stored procedure's argument within the `filter` is not yielding any results.